# How to get the length of a tree in python binary search

Tags: python

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data=None):
        self.data=data
        self.left_child=None
        self.right_child=None
        self.parent=None
        self.root = None
    
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None
    
    def add(self, data):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = Node(data)
        else:
            self.add_helper(data, self.root)

    def add_helper(self, data, cur_node):
        if data < cur_node.data:
            if cur_node.left_child == None:
                cur_node.left_child = Node(data)
                cur_node.left_child.parent = cur_node  # set parent
            else:
                self.add_helper(data, cur_node.left_child)
        elif data > cur_node.data:

            if cur_node.right_child == None:
                cur_node.right_child = Node(data)
                cur_node.right_child.parent = cur_node  # set parent
            else:
                self.add_helper(data, cur_node.right_child)

        else:
            print("data already in tree!")

     def __len__(self):
        if self.root is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return (self.__len__(self.left_child) + 1 +self. __len__(self.right_child))
```

So i am trying to return the length of the binary search tree list, so i tried using the **len** method for my binary search tree class. However, this is not working correctly. I need it to be able to not take in any parameters, and just return an integer for the length of the binary search tree list. What am i missing and what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You use self.__len__ before the function "self.__len__" is initialized because its part of itself. You propably receiving recursion error correct?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a helper function that takes a `Node` argument. Then do the recursion on the `left` and `right` of the node.

```
def __len__(self):
    return self.tree_len(self.root)

def tree_len(self, node):
    if node is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + max(self.tree_len(node.right_child), self.tree_len(node.left_child))
```